# How to connect means per group in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can do a scatterplot of two continuous variables like this:

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y = disp)) + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="auto", se=TRUE, fullrange=FALSE, level=0.95)
```

[image]

I use `cut` to create 5 groups of mpg intervals for cars (any better command would do as well). I like to see the intervals in the graph, thus they are easy to understand.

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(mpg_groups = cut(mpg, 5)) %>% 
  group_by(mpg_groups) %>% 
  mutate(mean_disp = mean(disp)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=mpg_groups, y = mean_disp)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

`mpg_groups` is a factor variable and can no longer be connected via  `geom_smooth()`.

```
# not working
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(mpg_groups = cut(mpg, 5)) %>% 
  group_by(mpg_groups) %>% 
  mutate(mean_disp = mean(disp)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=mpg_groups, y = mean_disp)) + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="auto", se=TRUE, fullrange=FALSE, level=0.95)
```

What can I do with easy (tidyverse) code in order to create the mean values per group and connect them via line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a more or less general rule, when drawing a line via `ggplot2` you have to explicitly set the `group` aesthetic in all cases where the variable mapped on `x` isn't a numeric, i.e. use e.g. `group=1` to assign all observations to one group which I call `1` for simplicity:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(mpg_groups = cut(mpg, 5)) %>%
  group_by(mpg_groups) %>%
  mutate(mean_disp = mean(disp)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg_groups, y = mean_disp, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "auto", se = TRUE, fullrange = FALSE, level = 0.95)
```

[image]